Why electric lines of the parallel plates does not contribute to electric field outside?
In general, if asked 'What is the electric field outside the two oppositely charged plates?' it will be zero (Fig.1 a).
The reason is said that, the electric field in between plates get added and outside get cancelled. But why the electric field on other sides not taken flowing like point charges. In some text , it given that some lines partially contribute,(Fig.1 b) but mostly approximated as 0. Why don't we take this outside electric field of parallel plates as like point charge distribution (Fig.2)? 

In a parallel plate arrangement, with the approximation that the separation of the plates is much less than the linear dimensions of the plates, the electric field outside the plates is neglected.
That is not to say that there is no electric field outside the plates rather that to a "good" approximation most of the energy associated with the electric field is contained between the plates.
So you diagram 1a tells the "correct" story whereas your diagram 1b is an approximation.
An easy way to show that diagram 1b is not correct is to consider moving a positive charge from the negative plate of diagram 1b to the positive plate.
Moving a positive charge between the plates from the negative plate to the positive plate requires external work to be done as the electric field between the plates is applying a force on the positive charge in the opposite direction to which it is moving.
However now consider the positive change emerging to the right of the negative plate in diagram 1b into a region where the is no electric field, then being moved to the left of the positive plate still in a region of no electric field and then reaching the positively charged plate.
No external work would be done which cannot be so as there is a potential difference across the plates.
The post Capacitor in a dielectric fluid illustrates another example which shows that an external electric field must exist.

How it is said 'two fields gets cancelled' in the outside region ? - I refer example 2.6 of David J.Griffiths 'Introduction to electrodynamics


I can't understand the lines starting 'However now consider the positive change emerging .....to....charged plate'- don't mind

Well explained ... but why these lines are not taken strongly like in the Fig.3 ? Since each point on plate has point charges arranged linearly

Diagram 2 is for two point charges. Things are different when there are lines of charges on conductors. Then the system tries to minimise the stored energy by making the electric field outside the parallel plates as small as possible.

Thank, I got some clarity

Additional question : How it is said 'two fields gets cancelled' in the outside region ? - I refer example 2.6 of David J.Griffiths 'Introduction to electrodynamics'

@RajeshR I have added a diagram to my answer.

So the electric field lines can cross the oppositely charged plates..right? And thank you for your effort @Farcher

Or any other reason for that

It is a diagram to show the "before" situation with the fields of each of the individual plates shown and then how the "after" (resultant") fields are consistent with the summation of the "before" fields.

thanks for taking time to answer

I asked this additional question elaborately with reference to boundary conditions- see if you can  (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/812070/397122)
